# How can I improve the performance for this junction table query

Tags: mysql, sql

There are SALARY table and COMPANY table.

I need to output companys' name list which AVG salary higher than 14000

## Expect output. Company name list

```
Baker Hughes Incorporated 
...
```

Here's my current query. I'd like to know if there are the more efficient way to query this?

```
SELECT NAME FROM COMPANY WHERE ID in (
    SELECT COMPANY_ID 
    FROM Salary S 
    GROUP BY COMPANY_ID Having  AVG(Salary) >= 140000
)
```

[image]

Comment: There's a good discussion of optimisation of this sort of subquery in the `WHERE` clause [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest form of the query is:

```
SELECT c.Name
FROM Company c JOIN
     Salary s
     ON s.COMPANY_ID = c.ID
GROUP BY c.Name, c.COMPANY_ID
HAVING AVG(s.Salary) >= 14000;
```

I would try this before trying other forms.  I would expect Zaynul's answer (using `EXISTS`) to be slightly faster with the right indexes, but sometimes MySQL surprises me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by using correlated subquery and do index on `ID` and `COMPANY_ID`

```
SELECT NAME FROM COMPANY c WHERE exists (
        SELECT 1  COMPANY_ID 
        FROM Salary s  where s.COMPANY_ID=c.ID
         Having  AVG(Salary) >= 140000
                   )
```

Comment: How come this method is faster than mine? ANy simple analysis or comment? thanks so much

Comment: @newBike incase of large data set return from subquery making large number of or operation because of IN operator but indexing and exists make better query plan compare to in so i said to you to try this one